# mapping spheres to cubes continuesly

Tags: calculus, general-topology, geometry, continuity

I'm trying to make some of the problems in my life adhere to nicer complexity classes, and I came across with this question:
Is there a continues bijection that maps spheres contained in the first quadrant of $\mathbb R^n$ to hyper cubes (not necessarily in the first quadrant) in  $\mathbb R^m$?

The spheres could vary in radius and center point as long as they are contained in the first quadrant.
There are no restrictions on the cubes.

Comment: No, because of dimensional invariance. There's no continuous bijection from an n-manifold an m-manifold.

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear, but m could equal n.

Comment: Ah, so if n=m, then yes there's exists a homeomorphism (continuous bijection with a continuous inverse). This is because a cube and sphere are homeomorphic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes if n = m.
Translate the  sphere so its center coincides with the center of the sphere.
Shrink the square until it is inside the circle.
Project radialy from the center, the cube onto the sphere.